# How to install SVN server when Apache HTTP Server is already installed in Windows?

Tags: apache, http, svn, windows-server-2016

I have a computer with `Windows Server 2016` operating system. It has `IIS 10` installed using ports 80 and 443 and `Apache HTTP Server 2.4` installed using port 81 and 4437.

Now I want to install SVN on it so that remote users can access it using http protocol. So I want SVN to use Apache HTTP Server. I went to https://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#windows web page to download SVN and looks like all products have Apache HTTP Server builtin.

Is there a documentation / video tutorial which tells step by step of installing in such scenario?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a documentation / video tutorial which tells step by step of
>   installing in such scenario?

The installation procedure remains the same when IIS or other httpd instances are running on the computer.